# Building and testing multiple apps - trying to understand appID's and profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to understand app ID's and provisioning profiles here, I'm quite lost.

I am a registered Apple Developer as an individual under my full name, and I have 2 applications currently in the works, and 2 device UDID's ready for testing.

I'd like to be able to build IPA's for these two apps, upload them to [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com), and use them on either of the UDIDs I have on me.

I have several questions (if I should ask separate questions, I'd be happy to unless someone happens to be willing to answer them, I'd appreciate it):

1) Because I have 2 (or more in the future) applications, do I need a wildcard app ID?

2) If I have the app ID `ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname.*` listed in the portal - WHAT is the actual appID - `ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname.*`, `ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname`, or `*`?

3) Why can't you delete an AppID in the portal?

4) I've read that this must match the name Bundle Identifier. Currently it sits at `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. What specifically needs to go here to 'match'?

5) Do I need to create separate distribution profiles for each app, or can I tell each new app to use the wildcard identifier?

6) How do I tie a specific target to a specific provisioning profile in XCode 4? (TestFlight suggests to use the distribution profile)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to either have a wildcard app id, or 2 separate (specific, non-wildcard) app ids, one each.
2. That is a wildcard app id, so the app id is *
3. No idea.
4. Your PRODUCT_ NAME, which you specify in the Packaging section of the Build Settings screen.
5. A single distribution profile will work with multiple apps if the app ID for that profile is a wild-card app id.  If they are specific app IDs, yes, you need a profile for each app.
6. You specify the provisioning profile in the Code Signing section of Settings, under CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.

Answer (score 1):

> Because I have 2 (or more in the future) applications, do I need a wildcard app ID?

You don't. In fact, I recommend against it, since it's probably only going to give you problems with the App Store in the future.

> If I have the app ID ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname.* listed in the portal - WHAT is the actual appID - ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname.*, ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname, or *?

That depends on the application. The first part is the Keychain space, which determines which applications can access the things you put in the Keychain. Then comes the actual application identifier, which is generally `company.projectname`. It would probably be `ET9WC78H9Q.com.mydevname.myapplication` in your case.

> Why can't you delete an AppID in the portal?

On Mac and iOS, the AppID is very important for applications like the App Store. They have to be unique, since having two of them could mean that applications get installed in the wrong place. This means that even if you could remove them you couldn't ever add them again, which means there's no point in deleting them.

> I've read that this must match the name Bundle Identifier. Currently it sits at ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}. What specifically needs to go here to 'match'?

Wouldn't worry too much about that - simply look at the target summary page (click the solution then click the target and finally go to the summary tab) and it'll tell you the name it automatically picked for you.

> Do I need to create separate distribution profiles for each app, or can I tell each new app to use the wildcard identifier?

You can definitely use the wildcard identifier, but the App Store will not necessarily like that.

> How do I tie a specific target to a specific provisioning profile in XCode 4? (TestFlight suggests to use the distribution profile)

Wouldn't worry too much about that. If you got the code signing set up correctly (look at the build settings, then pick the development and deployment certificates) then you have nothing to worry about.

Can't say much more in here since most App Store things are guarded by an NDA. Consider asking this on https://devforums.apple.com instead.

Comment: Thanks, at this point I'm not so much concerned with the App store as I am getting my apps(s) on the devices for testing and working with TestFlight.

Comment: Code signing for both is pretty much the same.